# how can I Convert "Tue Nov 26 2019 16:00:00 GMT-0800" to .net json date formate "\/Date(1574812800000)\/" formate?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime

I need to conver my ison date formate to .net json date formate in javascript

like this
Tue Nov 26 2019 16:00:00 GMT-0800" to "/Date(1574812800000)/"

Answer (score 1):

With JavaScript:

```js
var dt = new Date("Tue Nov 26 2019 16:00:00 GMT-0800");

var format = "/Date("+dt.valueOf()+")/";
console.log(format);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Moment.js:

```
moment("Tue Nov 26 2019 16:00:00 GMT-0800", "ddd MMM D YYYY H:m:s [GMT]ZZ").format("[/Date(]x[)/]")
```

You should get the result:

```
/Date(1574812800000)/
```

The timestamp you supplied corresponds to May 23, 2001 at midnight GMT.